# Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@7c8ce10f]

Tags: jsf, viewexpiredexception

I am serializing all the data in the session and storing the session data outside the JVM using tomcat persistence manager in the DB tables. Without persistence manager everything is working fine. But with the perisitence manager for this session storage. I am getting the following error when i click on any links in my web application.

```
Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@719abade]
viewId:/pages/foo.jsf - View /pages/foo.jsf could not be restored.
```

I've added the following to my web.xml

```
<context-param>  
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name> <param-value>true</param-value>  
</context-param>
```

Adding above configuration will solve the exception but the problem is click on any links don't work or it will not respond until i refresh the page. Seems some JSF life cycle issue. I am implementing `PhaseListener` to my class called `JSFPhaseListener` and configured that in `faces-config.xml` So I am thinking that this life cycle issue can be solved by doing something in my `JSFPhaseListener` class. Someone please help me to solve this one. My `JSFPhaseListener` class is given below.

```
public class JSFPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // Do your job here which should run right before the RENDER_RESPONSE.
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // Do your job here which should run right after the RENDER_RESPONSE.
    }

}
```

Comment: Using the `enableRestoreView11Compatibility` flag is absolutely not the correct solution. In order to really understand the problem and apply the correct solutions, see the duplicate.

Comment: @BalusC edited the question